# Анти дребезг срабатывания события в C#

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Интересует как реализовать срабатывания события не чаше чем например 2 сек. т.е. человек долбит по кнопке, на кнопку подписано событие, нужно чтобы при срабатывании события запускался какой то таймер отсчитывал интервал времени в течении которого событие не сработает. Вроде задача не сложная а с таймером получается много кода (запуск, проверка условия, сброс таймера). может это организовывается на async/await?

Заранее всем спасибо!!

Comment: Антидребезг? Прикольно, плюс :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проще простого.

```
bool isClickHot = false;
void OnClick(...)
{
    if (isClickHot) return;
    BlockClick();
    // ваш обработчик
}

async void BlockClick()
{
    isClickHot = true;
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    isClickHot = false;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Aldmi: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Интересное решение :)

Answer (score 7):

Вариант с `await Task.Delay` - рабочий, но он создает лишний таймер и использует пул потоков - в то время как именно эта задача довольно просто решается без него.

Вот так это делается с использованием `Stopwatch`:

```
private Stopwatch lastEvent;
public void OnEvent() {
  if (lastEvent != null && lastEvent.ElapsedMilliseconds < 2000) return;
  lastEvent = Stopwatch.StartNew();

  //...
}
```

Еще это можно сделать с помощью `Environment.TickCount` - но там код получается чуть сложнее; кроме того, `TickCount` зацикливается после примерно 49 дней аптайма (а простое сравнение начинает врать через 24 дня).

Использовать же `DateTime.Now` для измерения промежутков времени я не рекомендую - пользователь переведет системную дату и все повиснет.

---

PS Если такой подход вдруг кажется "недостаточно выразительным" - можно сделать служебную структурку для повышения этой самой выразительности:

```
public struct DebounceHelper {
  private TimeSpan delay;
  private Stopwatch lastEvent;

  public DebounceHelper(TimeSpan delay) {
    this.delay = delay;
    this.lastEvent = null;
  }

  public bool Test() {
    if (lastEvent != null && lastEvent.Elapsed < delay) return false;
    lastEvent = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    return true;
  }
}
```

Теперь основная часть кода окажется еще более красивой:

```
private DebounceHelper eventDebounceHelper = new DebounceHelper(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
public void OnEvent() {
  if (!eventDebounceHelper.Test()) return;

  //...
}
```

Comment: А почему `Task.Delay` использует пул потоков? Вроде ж не использует?

Comment: @VladD `Task.Delay` [использует](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5881) `Timer`, который [может использовать](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,388) пул потоков если несколько таймеров сработали одновременно. Плюс, что-то мне подсказывает, что для т.н. AppDomainTimer внутрях CLR используется таймер из WinAPI - а [они](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485(v=vs.85).aspx), опять-таки, без специального флага выполняются в потоках пула.

Comment: @VladD + в CoreCLR `AppDomainTimer` [использует](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/vm/comthreadpool.cpp#L1007) внутри `ThreadpoolMgr`, который [использует](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/726d1a3244b80bf963fd0d51e57d4bb90af1e426/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp#L5121) `QueueUserWorkItem` для любых таймеров. Хотя таймеры WinAPI там не используются, с ними я не угадал.

Comment: Well, но если даже так, поток занят не всё время, а только для вызова колбека, как я понимаю?

Comment: @VladD разумеется, поток пула нужен только для того чтобы послать оконное сообщение основному потоку, и все время не занят. Это совсем не `Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000))` :) Если бы использование пула в такой ситуации упрощало код - я бы не возражал. Но ведь и таймер создается, и пул дергается, и оконное сообщение шлется - и притом строчек кода больше...

Comment: Мне кажется, концептуально код с простым таском проще и выразительнее. А эффективность внутренних штук зависит от реализации, и в свете того, что мы находимся в UI, я бы считал всё, что не блокирует поток, одинаково эффективным с точностью до o(1).

Comment: В любом случае, много разных подходов — это хорошо. Пусть расцветут тысяча цветов (ц)

Comment: @VladD для "простоты и выразительности" надо классы-хелперы делать, а не подход менять :)

Comment: Возможно, класс-хелпер был бы ещё лучше. Напишете ваш вариант? Интересно, насколько выразительное API получится.

Comment: @VladD написал :)

Comment: Ага, так красивее, да.

Comment: Для красивой корректной сложной обработки нужно по идее использовать Rx. Но это за пределами этого вопроса (вот _некоторые участники_ обвиняют меня, что я из любого хелловорлд-вопроса пишу целый талмуд в виде ответа).

Comment: Точно не помню, но у событий вроде есть свойство - время, когда оно сработало. Можно его использовать для оценки как давно было предыдущее и никаких таймеров не надо. Запомнил время, потом сравнил с новым.

Comment: @Sergey это с каких пор оно там есть?.. Кроме того, алгоритм "запомнил время" очень уязвим к переводу системных часов назад.

Comment: @PavelMayorov `typedef struct tag MSG {
  HWND   hwnd;
  UINT   message;
  WPARAM wParam;
  LPARAM lParam;
  DWORD  time;
  POINT  pt;
} MSG, *PMSG, *LPMSG;` если `time` - не время события, то что это? при том что в описании прямо говорится - это время события. Не знаю наверняка, но не думаю, что при переводе из winapi в c# это поле уничтожается. Даже в javascript кажется есть отметка времени события. Кому надо проверит, в случае успеха получит профит, нет - пусть извращается с таймерами

Comment: @Sergey вы путаете понятия "событие" и "оконное сообщение"

Comment: @PavelMayorov и чем же они таким принципиальным отличаются, кроме названия?

Comment: @Sergey всем. Общего у них вообще ничего нет.